# Allowing Active Directory groups to sudo on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, active-directory, sssd

I've joined the domain and set up group login successfully, but can't get sudo to work for members of that group. `%DOMAIN\\domain-group ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers` doesn't work---users are not considered to be in sudoers. I think this has something to do with the way Ubuntu is interpreting the AD group because:

- The AD group settings are identical to other working groups, and `domain-group` works on RHEL servers.
- `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` is also identical to working RHEL servers.
- Domain user home directories, etc. are assigned to the `domain users` group as on working RHEL servers.
- I can give individual domain users sudo access via `/etc/sudoers`, but not the group.
- Logging in as a domain user gives the warning `groups: cannot find name for group ID 16720351`. When a domain user runs `id`, `domain-group` is associated with 16745417 instead of this gID.
- `domain-group` is not in `/etc/group`, but when I attempt to use `groupadd domain-group`to add the group manually, I get the error `groupadd: group 'domain-group' already exists`.

So what's the problem? Is there an Ubuntu-exclusive switch I need to flip or something?

Comment: Read `man nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Please can you fix your question so that if you mean `DOMAIN\\domain-group` then all your examples use that, and if you mean `domain-group` or `domain users ` or even `DOMAIN\\domain users` then everything uses that. It's really hard to work out what you mean with these apparent inconsistencies. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow AD Groups to SUDO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150476/allow-ad-groups-to-sudo)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not doing this on Ubuntu, so I don't know if there is something special there, but in CentOS I don't have to specify the domain in sudoers, so the syntax I use is:

```
%domain_group  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Groups with spaces in them have to escape the space

```
%Linux\ Admins       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```